# Error al ejecutar varios procedimientos almacenados

Tags: sql-server

Quisiera hacer una pregunta estoy trabajando con procedimientos almacenados en sql server y tengo en una query varios procedimientos 30 y fracción, y al intentar ejecutar todas presionando el botón "!Execute " de Microsoft SQL Management Studio, me aparece el siguiente error:

"A fatal scripting error occurred.Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing go."

Lo extraño es que si selecciono un procedimiento y presiono el boton execute, el procedimiento se agrega, pero si lo realizo todos a la vez aparece el error

comparto un extracto de código:

```
--TIPO SUCURSAL
create procedure ingresoTipoSucursal
@tipo varchar(100)
as

    if (@tipo <> 'ventas' or @tipo <> 'bodega' or @tipo <> 'administrativa')
        begin
            print 'Tipo de sursales solo son bodega, ventas ó administrativo '
        end
else
    begin
        insert into tipo_sucursal (tipo)
        values (@tipo)
        print 'Tipo de Sucursal Agregada'
    end
go

create procedure eliminarTipoSucursal
@id_tsucursal int
as
delete from tipo_sucursal where id_tsucursal = @id_tsucursal;
print 'Tipo de Sucursal Eliminada'
go

create procedure actualizarTipoSucursal
@id_t_sucursal int,
@tipo varchar(100)
as
UPDATE tipo_sucursal
SET
tipo = @tipo
WHERE
id_tsucursal = @id_t_sucursal
print 'Tipo de Sucursal Actualizada'
go

CREATE PROCEDURE listarTipoSucursal
as
    select * from tipo_sucursal

go


--CARGO
create procedure ingresoCargo
@carg_nombre varchar(100)
as
insert into cargo (carg_nombre)
values (@carg_nombre)
print 'Cargo agregado' 


go

create procedure eliminarCargo
@id_cargo int
as
delete from cargo where id_cargo = @id_cargo;
print 'Cargo Eliminado'
go

create procedure actualizarCargo
@id_cargo int,
@carg_nombre varchar(100)
as
UPDATE cargo
SET
carg_nombre = @carg_nombre
WHERE
id_cargo = @id_cargo
print 'Cargo Actualizado'
go

CREATE PROCEDURE listarCargo
as
    select * from cargo
```

se agradece cualquier ayuda

Comment: El código se comparte como texto. Replicar problemas desde una imagen es harto dispendioso y hace más difícil ayudar

Comment: Lo siento, lo he corregido, quisiera añadir una cosa más, copio el código en navicat y ejecuto todos los procedimientos a la vez y funciona perfectamente pero en el Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio no funciona dandome el error mencionado arriba.

Comment: Solucionado segun una respuesta del post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043465/creating-stored-procedure-syntax-relating-to-use-of-go     
que comenta : "If you go to "Save As...", click on the little down-arrow on the Save button and select "Save with Encoding..." then you can set your Line endings to Windows (CR LF). That seems to have resolved the issue for me..."

Comment: Tambien podrias ayudar a otra persona traduciendo la respuesta :)